# How to add datepicker in asp.net by using input control?

Tags: asp.net

I am using datapicker jquery but it is not working. Can anyone help me for that, I am new to Dnn. How to add datepicker in asp.net, by using input control? Any answer would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>

</div>
```

The Jquery website has some good examples of how to use the control and the different options you can apply. Are you trying to doing anything special?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Sorry , I downloaded jquery . i tried in above .. but its not working

Comment: Have you added the script reference to your page

Comment: <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/DNAiusItemblurs/js/datepicker.js" />

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>

Comment: <div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>

</div>

Comment: Try just adding this  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: That's all well and good,but I am using one check box if i checkin on that today date as to display and datepicker as to hide ,if i uncheckin datepicker as to display ,i tried many ways its not working,please let me know how to do,

Comment: <div class="demo"> <p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p> </div>  i am not able to call input id in c#

Comment: <input id="datepicker" type="test" runat="server"> then you can access it server side

Comment: ya i am using same but  in page date picker is not displaying.

Comment: <div class="demo">
         
<p>Date: <input id="datepicker" runat="server"  type="test" />

</p>
 
</div>